# Google cloud BigQuery undefined ValueList

Tags: go, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I'm working with the BigQuery API on Google Cloud Platform and I've completed the Golang client library installation.

When I try to compile, I see the following errors:

```
[root@server ~]$ go install github.com/user/program
# github.com/user/program/handler
go/src/github.com/user/program/handler/file1.go:228: undefined:
"cloud.google.com/go/bigquery".ValueList
go/src/github.com/user/program/handler/file1.go:259: undefined: 
"cloud.google.com/go/bigquery".ValueList
```

The offending line for 228 is:

```
227 for {
228     var values bigquery.ValueList
229     err := it.Next(&values)
```

At the top of the file I import the package, as normally

```
import "cloud.google.com/go/bigquery"
```

and have taken care to install the client library for Golang
    https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-go

I can see that the cloud.google.com package is contained within my GOPATH and I see the ValueList type decleration inside of a file in there. It is therefore puzzling that I'm getting this error.

**What's more:** I can compile this fine on my Windows machine with no errors. It's only when I try to do the same thing on my CentOS VM that I run into this. Both are running go version go1.6.3.

Thank you.

Comment: Is your GOPATH a single path?  Do you potentially have a vendor directory that has an older version of the library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Spikey,

Hi, please make sure you've installed correct client.
Here's why:

1. After installing go get -u cloud.google.com/go/bigquery I see that they *do not* have an exported ValueList type(!). Only valuelist, i.e. unexported. Check line 39 of ~go/src/google.golang.org/cloud/bigquery/value.go
2. However, they do mention ValueList as an exported type in their docs(!), for example:

   - line 52 of ~go/src/google.golang.org/cloud/bigquery/doc.go
   - https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/bigquery
   - line 164 of ~/go/src/google.golang.org/cloud/README.md
3. Also, ValueList is an exported type if looking directly at: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-go/blob/master/bigquery/value.go

So there's a confusion about installing a correct Google client.

Hope this helps!

Comment: you're absolutely right! My understanding was that using the command "go get cloud.google.com/go/bigquery" would grab the latest stable release from the repository. In this case it doesn't appear that this is actually happening maybe due to it being CentOS and go1.6.3 - thought I doubt this should have an impact.

Comment: I'll open an issue with the githubproject in case this is warranted. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just wanted to add a link to the issue that I opened and had closed. Seems like it was an inconsistency with their repo mirror that was since fixed. https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-go/issues/440